# Qlikview - Calendar - fromDate and toDate

Tags: calendar, qlikview

My calendar script is loading fine but the table not reflecting any changes. 
Below the code i am using:

```
Calendar:
load Distinct
"sDate",
Year("sShipment Date") As PostingYear,
Month("sShipment Date") As PostingMonth,
Week("sShipment Date") As PostingWeekOnly,
WeekDay("sShipment Date") As PostingWeekDay,
Day("sShipment Date") As PostingDay,
'Q' & Ceil(Month("sShipment Date")/3) As PostingQuarter
resident myTable;

Temp:
Load
min("sDate") as minDate,
max("sDate") as maxDate
Resident Calendar;

Let varMinDate = Num(Peek('minDate', 0, 'Temp'));
Let varMaxDate = Num(Peek('maxDate', 0, 'Temp'));
```

I create calendar object but when I pick the date I don't see change in my straight table.

[image: Capture.PNG]

I want when change start and end date to get result in my table between start and end date. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

In your calendar properties use the field selection and use an expression.

```
=MonthName(sdate)
```

For example and then this will give you the full range to select from.

This will then reflect in your straight table.